# Killer Ethernet E2400 not connecting 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, ethernet, atheros

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, with this hardware:

```
# E2400 Killer Ethernet
lspci -nn | grep 0200
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e0a1] (rev 10)
```

And this version of ubuntu:

```
Linux lilezek-desktop 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 26 19:39:52 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

alx's modinfo:

```
# modinfo alx 
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-47-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Qualcomm Atheros(R) AR816x/AR817x PCI-E Ethernet Network Driver
author:         Qualcomm Corporation, <nic-devel@qualcomm.com>
author:         Johannes Berg <johannes@sipsolutions.net>
srcversion:     80B89D6BA6F4A4F4A917E3C
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E0A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mdio
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-47-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

More info about ALX and ifconfig:

```
# ifconfig
enp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW ::ec  
      ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
      Paquetes RX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      Paquetes TX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
      Bytes RX:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupción:16 

# lsmod | grep alx
alx                    36864  0
mdio                   16384  1 alx

# dmesg | grep alx
[   21.416362] alx 0000:05:00.0 eth1: Qualcomm Atheros AR816x/AR817x Ethernet [1c:1b:0d:68:96:ec]
[   21.440970] alx 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: renamed from eth1

# dmesg | grep enp
[  113.422322] alx 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Up: 100 Mbps Full
[  113.554797] alx 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: fatal interrupt 0x200, resetting
[  113.556538] alx 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Up: 100 Mbps Full
[  113.689014] alx 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: fatal interrupt 0x200, resetting
[  113.690728] alx 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: NIC Up: 100 Mbps Full
# unplug cable    
[  113.796813] alx 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link Down
[  113.823228] alx 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: fatal interrupt 0x200, resetting
[  113.957444] alx 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: fatal interrupt 0x200, resetting
[  114.091661] alx 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: fatal interrupt 0x200, resetting
[  114.201293] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp5s0: link is not ready
[  114.225878] alx 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: fatal interrupt 0x200, resetting
[  114.360092] alx 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: fatal interrupt 0x200, resetting
[  114.494306] alx 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: fatal interrupt 0x200, resetting
```

Which is updated. Everything was working but I changed my motherboard which had a Gigabit Ethernet Controller to a new motherboard with E2400 Killer Ethernet Controller.

Could it be that changing the hardware is making Ubuntu not to work properly?

Regards,
lilEzek.

Comment: What does this teminal command tell us: `modinfo alx | grep E0A1`

Comment: Check again the question.

Comment: Does the module load? `lsmod | grep alx` If not, load it: `sudo modprobe alx` Is an interface created? `ifconfig` Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep alx`

Comment: I'm sorry about the lack of info. I'm not used to have problems with the drivers.

Comment: Everything looks entirely normal so far! Let's look at the log as you are trying to connect: `dmesg | grep enp` And also: `sudo ethtool enp5s0` As the result will be lengthy, please paste the results here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Done. I truncated the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this post: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=215169 The poster has the same symptoms; a not-working ethernet and the error message:

```
fatal interrupt 0x200, resetting
```

He solved it by disabling IOMMU is the BIOS. Please try it. If it is ineffective, we'll try the GRUB parameter option.

Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Change the line:

```
GRUB_LINUX_CMD_LINE=""
```

To read:

```
GRUB_LINUX_CMD_LINE="iommu=soft"
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Get the system to re-read the file and use the changes:

```
sudo update-grub
```

You should be all set.

Comment: IOMMU is enabled. If I disable IOMMU I lose USB control. No USB works with IOMMU disabled with this motherboard. Any idea?

Comment: I have fixed it by disabling IOMMU, and then setting iommu=soft on GRUB option.  I upvote you because it was very useful and I'll choose your answer as correct if you add the `iommu=soft` boot option to your answer.

Comment: Please see my edit above. I'm glad it's fixed.