# Another , Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200 ethernet controller post

Tags: networking, drivers, atheros, 21.10

Ubuntu 21.10

uname -r

```
5.13.0-21-generic
```

tail -f /var/log/syslog

```
alx 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full
alx 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: fatal interrupt 0x200, resetting
..
alx 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full
alx 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: fatal interrupt 0x200, resetting¿
```

i try backports and nothing good happen (off 3.x.x to 5.x.x)
https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/

i try the old tutorials for this post.. (compat-drivers)
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008332

i have a hub with eth anyway, hope someone have a solution or i go for windows :(

Setup (i use this like home-server)
Fx 6100 , GYGABITE 990-GA - 16gb ram

Comment: Did you try this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/853881/killer-ethernet-e2400-not-connecting-16-04 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks chili555 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to chili555

i have IOMMU activated on bios, turn off and now is working

ip a

```
 enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:8d:5c:bc:57:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.62/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp4s0
       valid_lft 3500sec preferred_lft 3500sec
    inet6 fe80::41db:4d24:a80a:4cd5/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

[Killer Ethernet E2400 not connecting 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853881/killer-ethernet-e2400-not-connecting-16-04)

Comment: Awesome! Glad it’s working!