# Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller not working

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, 22.04

My Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller and BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter suddenly stopped working, and I'm unable to get it working again.

The output from `lshw -C network` is:

```
    *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df400000-df407fff memory:df200000-df3fffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df600000-df63ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

and output from `lspci -knn | grep Eth is`:

```
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e0a1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1462:7978]
```

The ubuntu version is 22.04 LTS (jammy)

I have tried disabling IOMMU in the BIOS as suggested in this post [Killer Ethernet E2400 not connecting 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853881/killer-ethernet-e2400-not-connecting-16-04).

This is the output from `sudo modprobe alx`:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module alx not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-43-generic
```

Additional wireless information: https://pastebin.com/81rz0eG3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While booted into the earlier kernel version where the ethernet does work, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-43-generic
```

Reboot. You should be all set.